# REGEX Test all characters in a string

Tags: php, regex

I am using the code (at the bottom) to test some strings for non-US characters, the following code is returning:

```
int(1)
int(1)
int(1)
```

The result I am looking for is the first and thrid dump should be 0 and the second dump should be 1 like so:

```
int(0)
int(1)
int(0)
```

Here is my test code:

```
<?php
$str[] = '漢語';
$str[] = 'abc123';
$str[] = '漢語abc123';
var_dump(preg_match("/\p{Common}+/u", $str[0]));
var_dump(preg_match("/\p{Common}+/u", $str[1]));
var_dump(preg_match("/\p{Common}+/u", $str[2]));
```

Right now it just tests to see if there is 1 US Character, but I need to test all the characters. What can I do to test ALL of the characters to get my expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, what you expect `\p{common}` to match. I have never used it and I am not sure what is included in that script.

Maybe a class like `[\p{Latin}\p{Nd}]` would be more what you want?

`\p{Latin}` are Latin characters, not sure what it is included, a quick test showed that e.g. ÖÄÜ are also included

`\p{Nd}` a digit 0-9

For more information have a look at [Unicode Regular Expressions on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

So, this brings your expected result:

```
$str[] = '漢語';
$str[] = 'abc123';
$str[] = '漢語abc123';
var_dump(preg_match("/^[\p{Latin}\p{Nd}]+$/u", $str[0]));
var_dump(preg_match("/^[\p{Latin}\p{Nd}]+$/u", $str[1]));
var_dump(preg_match("/^[\p{Latin}\p{Nd}]+$/u", $str[2]));
```

Comment: here is my final result: `/^[\p{Latin}\p{Nd}\p{Common}]*$/u`